# Using MongoDB on Discord.py for scheduled tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, discord.py, scheduled-tasks

## Purpose

I have some commands like temp-mute, temp-ban, and other commands that need to be done after commands execution, and I do need to schedule things like giveaways and trigger a function as soon as the subscription ends, from a command.

## What do I want?

I want to store all my timings and things in MongoDB and then make it trigger at the time that the function needs to be triggered. I currently use `await asyncio.sleep(seconds)`, but that stops when I restart the bot or if the bot goes offline, I want the function to trigger as soon as it comes online if the time is passed, or I want it to trigger on time even after the bot restarts.

Comment: You can fetch the data from the database and make a few tasks that will sleep till the time it's over, also it's worth mentioning that the max seconds that asyncio can sleep is `3456000` seconds (40 days). I doubt anyone will answer this question at all, it's too vague, with no details at all, it also seems that you want us to code this for your, without making an attemp, I'm voting to close because this is a wishlist, not a programming question, take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@tasks.loop()`.

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
cluster = MongoClient("mongo_url_here")
collection = cluster["name"]
```

This might be how you describe the collection. Now , when you temp ban or temp mute someone you need to save the final time. You can do this like this ,

```py
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
final_time = current_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds_here)
```

Save the `final_time` in the database then.

Now you need to create a `@tasks.loop(seconds=x)`

x means that "after every x seconds the function inside `@tasks.loop()` will run

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def checker(self):
    try:
        all = collection.find({}) # return all documents inside the db
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        async for x in all:
            if current >= x["Time"]: # do stuff after this
            else:
                pass
    except Exception:
        pass
```

`x["Time"]` -> This can be a variable in document which stores the `final_time`

{"id" : id , "Time" : final_time} -> Like this

Now ,
`async def checker(self):` -> Checker is a function , you need to start it. It depends on whether you are using cog or not

If not -> `checker.start()` # Anywhere in code to start

If it is cog -> `self.checker.start()` # Should be placed inside `**init**